# Compact connected spaces have non- cut points

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact connected Hausdorff space with more than one point. Prove that there is point $x \in X$ s.t. $X \setminus \{x\}$ is connected.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the way it's phrased makes it seem like a homework problem.

Comment: Let me assure you that it is homework! I'm older than posting my homework here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was typing up an answer, but I must go. So I will refer you to the answer. In [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC225168/pdf/pnas00124-0026.pdf), at the bottom of page 380, there is a proof that there are at least 2 non-cut points.

Comment: You had a nice proof which was unfortunately too long for your *time* margin to contain.......