# If $X$ is a connected subset of a connected space $M$ then the complement of a component of $M \setminus X$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have an exercise found on a list but I didn't know how to proceed. Please, any tips?

*Let $X$ be a connected subset of a connected metric space $M$. Show that for each connected component $C$ of $M\setminus X$ that $M\setminus C$ is connected.*

Comment: Interestingly, this was used to answer this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153376/antisymmetry-among-cut-points/156333#156333) a few days ago.

Comment: Ow. What a surprise! So, maybe there is the proof on that book. Thanks.

Comment: I have written the main ideas of proofs in that answer. They might be useful to you, the details probably won't be too hard to fill in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the theorem found on Kuratowski's book. Thanks for the reference, it is a very excellent book.
[image: print screen]

---

The Theorem II.4 cited above:

[image: Theorem II.4]

Comment: what is the Theorem II, 4 referred to in the proof? I don't see why $C \cup M$ must be connected... in fact, it seems that $M$ must lie in components of $\mathcal{X} - A$ other than $C$.

Comment: I edited above.