# Is there a connected topological space which becomes disconnected by removing any point?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness

I wonder if there is a connected space $X$ such that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is disconnected (not necessarily totally disconnected) for every $x\in X$.

**update:** This question comes from the case where I try to remove a connected proper subset from a connected space as big as possible. One of my friend tell me that this is trivial since I will always get a singleton. I thought this may be proved or disproved by thinking about the existence of a space satisfies the property in my childish question above.
I start to think this question by consider plane figures and then fall into confusion.

Thinks to the earnest answers to point out that these questions are obvious.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/634787/

Comment: $(0,1)$?${}{}{}$

Comment: You wonder? Have you tried to find any? How? I know nothing about Topology, but you should show the effort you put into trying to find an answer to a question while asking it here.

Comment: Any simplicial tree.

Comment: ...without leaves (valence 1 vertices)!

Comment: You are right. I misundertood this question. It is easy to find examples. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try for example: $X=\mathbb R$?

Note that in $\mathbb R$ a subset $A$ is connected if and only if $A$ is an interval.