# Connected space whose every subspace is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

We know that a subspace of a connected space can be disconnected eg. $\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbf{R}$ where $\mathbf{R}$ is connected but $\mathbf{Q}$ is totally disconnected as a subspace. 
My question is, 
"Does there exists a topological space such that every proper subspace (except singletons) is disconnected but the whole space is connected".

Comment: Singletons are always connected. You surely mean every non-trivial subspace with at least two elements?

Comment: yes otherwise it would be trivial

Comment: I don't know about every proper subspace, but for an example of a connected space which gets totally disconnected after you remove one point see [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster-Kuratowski_fan)

Comment: The two-point indiscrete (trivial) space? (This is a bit of a degenerate example, I know.)

Comment: Niels Diepeveen's answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634787/is-there-an-infinite-connected-topological-space-such-that-every-space-obtained should answer your question since such a space would become totally disconnected upon removing any point.