# Connected space such that (almost) no subspace is connected

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Is there a connected space $(X,\tau)$ such that $X$ has more than $2$ points and the only proper connected subsets of $X$ are the singletons?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634787/is-there-an-infinite-connected-topological-space-such-that-every-space-obtained) seems relevant.

Comment: @DavidMitra It's basically the same question with the assumption "$X$ is infinite" added, no?

Comment: It appears to me that the question you are referring to is a bit stronger. My question could be rephrased as "Is there a topological space $(X,\tau)$ with more than 3 points such that given $x\neq y\in X$ the only connected subset containing $x$ and $y$ is $X$?"