# Connected open proper subsets of a connected complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a connected complete metric space with more than one point. Must $X$ contain a non-singleton non-empty connected proper open subset?

Comment: Thank you to Daniel and David.

Comment: Can a small open ball be disconnected?

Comment: The Theorem in the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153376/antisymmetry-among-cut-points) implies that it does.

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't see how. We can get a nontrivial proper connected subset from the theorem, but does it have to be open?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Oops. I forgot about the open condition.

Answer (score 3):

Probably yes.

**Theorem.** If $X$ is a connected separable metric space or compact Hausdorff space with more than one point, then $X$ has a proper open connected subset.

proof. Clearly $X$ is infinite.  Thus if $X\setminus \{x\}$ is connected for any $x\in X$, then you have an open set as desired. If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then $X$ has a non-cut point, and so we're done.

Otherwise, every point of $X$ is a cut-point. In Topology. Vol. II by K. Kuratowski [Theorem 1, page 160], it is shown that for a connected separable metric space $Z$, the set $Z\setminus \{z\}$ is connected or is the union of two connected sets for every $z\in Z$ except for a countable set of points of $Z$. As $X$ is uncountable,   for some $x\in X$ we have that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is the union of two disjoint connected open sets. Either one of these works for the desired open set.